# Getting around Qt's templating restrictions

Tags: c++, qt, templates, design-patterns, qtnetwork

I want to write a simple flexible ftp server in C++ that can be parametrized with a class to handle the user (check login and password, deliver files etc.) supplied on server initialization.

So I came up with this neat (so I thought) idea:

```c
class FtpDelegate
{
public:
    FtpDelegate() {}
    virtual ~FtpDelegate() {}
    virtual bool login(QString username, QString password) = 0;
    // ...
};

class DummyDelegate : public FtpDelegate
{
public:
    virtual bool login(QString username, QString password)
    {
        return true;
    }
};

template<class Delegate>
class FtpServer : public QObject, Derived_from<Delegate, FtpDelegate>
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FtpServer(const QHostAddress &address = QHostAddress::Any,
                       quint16 port = 21,
                       QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void newConnection();

private:
    QTcpServer *server;
    QHostAddress address;
};

template <class Delegate>
void FtpServer<Delegate>::newConnection()
{
    FtpDelegate *delegate = new Delegate();
    new FtpConnection (delegate, server->nextPendingConnection(), address, this);
}

class FtpConnection : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FtpConnection(FtpDelegate *delegate,
                           QTcpSocket *socket,
                           const QHostAddress &address,
                           QObject *parent = 0);

public slots:
    void newDataConnection();

private:
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    QTcpServer *dataServer; // needed to transfer data to user
    QTcpSocket *dataSocket;
};


// server initialization
FtpServer<DummyDelegate> ftpServer();
```

and then (you probably saw that coming) bam!

```
Error: Template classes not supported by Q_OBJECT
```

it is likely that there are other errors or misconceptions too as I am only starting to learn the C++ template mechanism (and Qt as well).

My question is: what is the best way to make it work without using ugly hacks like passing function pointers or needing to create a factory implementation for each concrete FtpDelegate's derived class. Maybe there's some clever design pattern I just can't see. Eventually I can rewrite the network mechanism to boost if it is the best option.

Comment: Why do you want the `Delegate` to be part of `FtpServer`'s type? Why not just store a pointer to a `Delegate` in your `FtpServer`?

Comment: This is one of the situations where "normal" inheritance/polymorphism works perfectly well, don't pollute your code with tons of useless templates just because.

Comment: @TomKnapen I need to be able to create a new instance of Delegate for each new user connection (see implementation of FtpServer::newConnection()).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I'm totally for simplicity but don't see a way to get rid of thos templates. Could you elaborate? Regarding inheritance - the only thing coming to my mind is merging FtpDelegate and FtpConnection but it doesn't solve the problem anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to create a template Q_OBJECT class (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4397478/476681) and answers).

Instead of using static inheritance, you should use a run-time inheritance, and inject an object inheriting from FtpDelegate class.

---

It looks like the FtpServer is actually a factory creating connections. From your question, I do not see why it has to be Q_OBJECT class. So you may need to reconsider your design, and simplify that class.

---

> what is the best way to make it work without using ugly hacks like passing function pointers or needing to create a factory implementation for each concrete FtpDelegate's derived class.

The best way may be to have a factory class, which creates instances of `FtpDelegate` type. But you have so many problems in the posted code, that it is not possible to tell more without knowing all gory details.

Comment: Actually the FtpServer does handle the main server and passes the socket associeted with a new connected peer (signaled with FtpServer::newConnection) to newly created FtpConnection instance. 

On the other hand, the FtpConnection creates a new server that manages data transfer (this is the ftp specification's requirement). Both classes inherit from QObject so they can use qt's signals and slots.

I know I have to do some redesigning and that's why I'm asking for help :)