# How to resolve template issue in Qt

Tags: c++, templates, qt4.7

Hi i am trying to write a template class in Qt,while doing so i was got stuck with some errors,i have read some articles and started to build an example according to my requirement

template.h

```
#ifndef CSLCDTEMPLATE_H
#define CSLCDTEMPLATE_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QList>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QPalette>
#include <QStringList>


template<class T>
class LcdTemplate : public QDialog
{
public:
    LcdTemplate();
    void display(T);
    T Getalue();

private slots:
    void display();
private:
    int indexVal;
    T m_Obj;
    QStringList nameList;
};

#endif
// CSLCDTEMPLATE_H
```

template.cpp

```
#include "CSLcdTemplate.h"

extern QStringList display_list;

template <class T>
LcdTemplate<T>::LcdTemplate()
{
    qDebug()<<"Inside the Constructor of LCD Template";

    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
#ifdef GL11_QT
    setGeometry(0,0,320,240);
#endif
#ifdef GL11_GNOME
    setGeometry(2,20,316,200);
#endif
    setStyleSheet("background-color:yellow");

    indexVal = 0;

    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(display()));
    timer->start(500);

    QTimer::singleShot(4000, this, SLOT(close()));
}

//template <class T>
void LcdTemplate::display()
{

    nameList = display_list;
    qDebug()<<"Data in"<<nameList;
    display(nameList);

}

template <class T>
void LcdTemplate<T>::display(T list)
{
    switch(indexVal)
    {
    case 0:
        this->setStyleSheet(nameList.at(indexVal));
        indexVal = 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        this->setStyleSheet(nameList.at(indexVal));
        indexVal = 2;
        break;
    case 2:
        this->setStyleSheet(nameList.at(indexVal));
        indexVal = 3;
        break;
    case 4:
        this->setStyleSheet(nameList.at(indexVal));
        indexVal = 4;
        break;
    case 5:
        this->setStyleSheet(nameList.at(indexVal));
        indexVal = 0;
        break;
    }
}

template <class T>
T TestTemp<T>::Getalue()
{
   return m_Obj;
}
```

The errors i am facing are

```
CSLcdTemplate.cpp:29:6: error: 'template<class T> class LcdTemplate' used without template parameters
CSLcdTemplate.cpp: In function 'void display()':
CSLcdTemplate.cpp:32:5: error: 'nameList' was not declared in this scope
CSLcdTemplate.cpp: At global scope:
CSLcdTemplate.cpp:67:11: error: expected initializer before '<' token
```

How can i resolve this errors.

Comment: Template implementation in a cpp file??? Have a look at [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl). Yet, there are some limited cases you still can do this, but in general you will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix the template class and the class responsible for signals and slots. See [QT : Templated Q_OBJECT class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397478/qt-templated-q-object-class)

Note that the correct syntax for template class member definition is

```
template <class T>
void LcdTemplate<T>::display()
{}
```

Note that you need to add the Q_OBJECT macro as well for signal and slots to work.

Comment: I thought it's not possible to create a QObject that's a template. Did that change recently or something?

Comment: I too read in some articles while searching for the solution,so i am trying to build the example using inheritance but i was unable to achieve using inheritance too.Looking for more elaborated examples.

Comment: @Mounika  don't do it. Can you elicit why you think you need inheritance??

Comment: I have read in some articles that we can't directly use Q_OBJECT in a template class.In order to resolve i have rewritten my code by writing all signals and slots in a class and derived the template class from signals and slots class and overridden the methods.It would be better if you can look at my code.how can post the new code..?

Comment: If you override the methods, and you need these methods to be signals or slots, you NEED the Q_OBJECT in the derived class. Which means you are back to square one. I suggest you to use composition instead of inheritance.