# Qt: Emit signal when QPointer is changed

Tags: c++, qt, templates, qpointer

I want to make a class similar to `QPointer` (or subclass it) which will emit a signal whenever the internal pointer gets changed.

Unfortunately I need to inherit `QObject` class to be able to emit signals and also I think I need to use templates to be able to store a specific type of pointer. But according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397478/qt-templated-q-object-class) it is not possible to mix `QObject` with templates.

Any idea how to make my class which keeps track on internal pointer changes?

Comment: Just throwing an idea : create a class inheriting `QObject` that just have a function `emitPointerChange` wich actually emits a signal, and do a composition in the templated class of this custom-emitter-object. Then you would need to connect your slots to the `MyQPointer::m_emitter` pointer instead of the `QPointer` itself, is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [QPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointer.html#details) when you want to **guard** a `QObject` subclass instance. If the referenced pointer is deleted, QPointer is set to `0`:

```
QLabel * label = new QLabel();
QPointer pointer = label;
delete label;
if(pointer) //false
{
//...
```

Since the held object is a QObject subclass, you can connect a slot to its `destroyed` signal, to track when it's deleted (and the QPointer is set to zero).

If a `QPointer` got reassigned, instead, no destroyed signal will be emitted

```
pointer = new QLabel();
```

the formerly held object is only left unguarded, but not deleted.

To track the pointer reset, you'd be better using [QSharedPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#details), instead.
When the `QSharedPointer` held object is cleared or reset, and the internal reference count gets to zero, `delete` is called on the held object (and if it's a QObject subclass, the destroyed signal is emitted).

If you go for a DIY smart pointer, I suggest to use a QObject derived class for emitting signals and own an instance of it in your pointer class:

```
class Emitter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Emitter() : QObject(0) {}
    void forward(void * p) { emit reset(p); }
signals:
    void reset(void *);
};

template <typename T>
class Pointer
{
public:
    Pointer() : instance(0){}
    void connect(QObject * receiver, const char * slot)
    {
        QObject::connect(&emitter, SIGNAL(reset(void*)), receiver, slot);
    }
    void set(T* t)
    {
        emitter.forward(instance);
        instance = t;
    }

    //...

private:
    Emitter emitter;
    T * instance;
};
```

Obviously, the above code is **not** intended as a smart pointer implementation, just an example to show how to emit signals from a class template.

To connect a slot (say from a Form class):

```
Pointer<QLabel> p;
p.connect(this, SLOT(pointerreset(void*)));
```

The void pointer passed to the slot is the T pointer held before reset. To simplify the unavoidable cast, you can add to the Pointer class a helper method like this:

```
T * cast(void * p) { return static_cast<T*>(p); }
```

This way, for a `Pointer<QLabel> pointer`, in a slot:

```
void Form::pointerreset(void * p)
{
    QLabel * label = pointer.cast(p);
    //...
}
```

Depending on your smart pointer implementation, you could consider not to use the old pointer at all and just emit a signal with no arguments. Maybe there's no reason to access the old object further, especially if it is about to be deleted.

Comment: In he meantime I found the exactly same solution :) The only pain is that signal `reset(void*)` does not provide templated pointer type, but only a generic `void *` pointer. In this case it is more comfortable to add a getter to `Pointer`class than always retype the pointer in the argument. Anyway, thank you for your solution!

Comment: When you access the held instance, after the signal has been received, are you 100% sure it refers to the old one and not to the newly set instance? I would pass the void pointer and cast it using the helper method I added to the answer.

Comment: Very nice solution, +1