# Struggling to bind a pointer to a member function to a T member of a class template then called in a slot

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to create a connection(`QObject::connect`) at run time.

I wanted to pass a pointer to a member function to another class template. It complied successfully, but link errors raised at run time.

**DynamicSlotCreator.h:**

```
template <typename OBJ, typename FUNC>
class DynamicSlotCreator : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT;

private:
    OBJ obj;
    FUNC func;

public:
    DynamicSlotCreator(OBJ o, FUNC f) :
        obj(o), func(f)
    {}

public slots:

    void dynamicSlot()
    {
        (obj.*f)();
    }

};
```

**main.cpp:**

```
class Function
{
public:
    void greet()
    {
        qDebug() << "hello world";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QPushButton* pb = new QPushButton("Btn");
    pb->show();

    Function x;
    DynamicSlotCreator<Function, decltype(&Function::greet)> dsc(x, &Function::greet);

    QObject::connect(pb, SIGNAL(clicked()), &dsc, SLOT(dynamicSlot()));

    return a.exec();

}
```

**ERRORS:**

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl DynamicSlotCreator<class Function,void (__cdecl Function::*)(void)>::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@?$DynamicSlotCreator@VFunction@@P81@EAAXXZ@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl DynamicSlotCreator<class Function,void (__cdecl Function::*)(void)>::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@?$DynamicSlotCreator@VFunction@@P81@EAAXXZ@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)
1>main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl DynamicSlotCreator<class Function,void (__cdecl Function::*)(void)>::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@?$DynamicSlotCreator@VFunction@@P81@EAAXXZ@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the error output as text instead.

Comment: The problem is most likely [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file?rq=1) Because of how Qt works, some of the implementation will be in auto-generated source files.

Comment: I doubt you can use templates in this way. Signal/slot connection code generated by Qt moc tool **before** the compilation, while class template instantiated at compile time.

Comment: dont confuse runtime errors with linker errors. Linker errors happen long before you can run it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Wasn't it implemented in a header file?

Comment: `Q_OBJECT` is a macro that adds some functions, and these functions will be implemented in an automatically generated source file by the `moc` tool.

Comment: @vahancho oh that makes sense

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude alright Is there a possible way to do the same thing?

Comment: It is not possible to mix template and Q_OBJECT, see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397478/qt-templated-q-object-class)

Comment: Assuming you're using Qt5 why not just [pass a lambda to `QObject::connect`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-4)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a pointer to a function, you need to pass a pointer to [QAction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaction.html)
Something like this:

```
auto action = new QAction(myClass1);
connect(action, &QAction::triggered, myClass1, &MyClass1::myFunction);
... --> action
auto button = new QPushButton(myClass2);
connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, action, &QAction::trigger);
```